# data into custom redshift schema using aws glue

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue, database-schema

While loading data on Target Redshift using AWS Glue, we see the only three schemas:
*. public
*. pg_catalog
*. information_schema

I don't see the custom **schema** created on redshift DB which I created to load table in that schema.

*I will appreciate a help on this*.